# PHP mail slowdown is hanging the page

Tags: php, sendmail

I've got a weird mail issue.  Specifically, I have a script that checks the request header, and if it matches a certain string it sends out a mail using `mail()`.  It's a basic mail, with the standard 'to', 'subject', 'content', 'from' fields and nothing else.

The mail does get sent out fine, but it causes the page load to hang for 30+ seconds (even with `mail()` outside the generated HTML), far too long.  I saw some responses suggesting dump the mails into a db and run a cron job on it, but that's not really an option in this situation.

Basically, I'm wondering if there's a way to force a php script (the page load) completion without `mail()` completing or some configuration I should be checking that could be causing this to take so long.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once on a RHEL 4 server and found 2 solutions that worked: using PEAR mail or using an external smtp server (gmail in my case). Sending a simple contact form went from 30 - 50 seconds to less than a second.

I never found out what caused it...

Answer (score 0):

Never had problems with `mail()`, i find it very reliable.

- The problem occurs in all e-mails or with specific ones?
- Did you tried to test the code on another server?
- Use `PHPmailer()` from [here](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) as alternative (if possible) with SMTP. [Here](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/)'s a good tutorial.

Comment: The problems occur in any php-created emails using the `mail()` function.  The server setup itself is 'interesting', to say the least, and I wouldn't be surprised if the server limitations are what's causing the slowdown.  I hesitate to rework too much of the server itself, as it's getting replaced in 4-6 months - it's more a matter of "make this work for now" than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

When I had similar problem, it was caused by the absence of canonical hostname.

Look at `/var/log/mail.err`: if you see

> sendmail[31575]: unable to qualify my own domain name (localhost) -- using short name"

then that's it!

Then you need:

1. Add your hostname to `/etc/hosts` as: `your.ip.address your.host.name`
2. Set the hostname in `/etc/hostname` as: `your.host.name`
3. Reboot